How to increase the precision of scipy.optimize.fsolve function
I want to model PCR reactions, so I have a bunch of algebraic non-linear equations that I and solving using the fsolve function. But after 23 cycles the float overflows and the results come out incorrect. By incorrect i mean that the values of the variables (x[0], x[1], ..) become negative.
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, least_squares
import numpy as np

cycles = 35

KH1 = 5.5531*(10**-13)
KH2 = 8.1493*(10**-11)
KP = 10**-2

P1 = [None] * (cycles+1)
P2 = [None] * (cycles+1)
T1 = [None] * (cycles+1)
T2 = [None] * (cycles+1)
H1 = [None] * (cycles+1)
H2 = [None] * (cycles+1)


P1[0] = 10**-6
P2[0] = 10**-6
T1[0] = 10**-11
T2[0] = 10**-11

p1 = P1[0]
p2 = P2[0]
t1 = T1[0]
t2 = T2[0]


def func(x):
    e1 = (x[4] * KH1) - (x[0] * x[2])
    e2 = (x[5] * KH2) - (x[1] * x[3])
    e3 = p1 - (x[0] + x[4] + x[6])
    e4 = p2 - (x[1] + x[5] + x[6])
    e5 = t1 - (x[2] + x[4])
    e6 = t2 - (x[3] + x[5])
    e8 = (x[6] * KP) - (x[0] * x[1])
    return [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e8]

for i in range(cycles):
    sol = fsolve(func, [0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001])

    H1[i] = sol[4]
    H2[i] = sol[5]

    fH1 = H1[i] / T1[i]
    fH2 = H2[i] / T2[i]
    
    efficiency = 0.5 * (fH1 + fH2)
    
    print(i+1)
    print(efficiency)
    
    P1[i+1] = P1[i] - H1[i]
    P2[i+1] = P2[i] - H2[i]
    T1[i+1] = T1[i] + H2[i]
    T2[i+1] = T2[i] + H1[i]

    p1 = P1[i+1]
    p2 = P2[i+1]
    t1 = T1[i+1]
    t2 = T2[i+1]


Is there a way to increase the precision of the results for at least 35 cycles.
The output for 35 cycles:
Cycle: 1; Efficiency: 0.9999589746574444
Pri 1: 9.999900000055537e-07
Pri 2: 9.999900008149532e-07
Temp 1: 1.9999185046783575e-11
Temp 2: 1.999999444636531e-11
Cycle: 2; Efficiency: 0.9999589738335422
Pri 1: 9.999700008316142e-07
Pri 2: 9.999700024504453e-07
Temp 1: 3.999754955458496e-11
Temp 2: 3.999916838595971e-11
Cycle: 3; Efficiency: 0.9999589721929882
Pri 1: 9.999300033042744e-07
Pri 2: 9.99930006542e-07
Temp 1: 7.999345799992356e-11
Temp 2: 7.999669572574256e-11
Cycle: 4; Efficiency: 0.9999589689112148
Pri 1: 9.998500098907068e-07
Pri 2: 9.998500163665432e-07
Temp 1: 1.5998363345666242e-10
Temp 2: 1.599901092934185e-10
Cycle: 5; Efficiency: 0.9999589623463345
Pri 1: 9.99690026346127e-07
Pri 2: 9.996900392996067e-07
Temp 1: 3.1996070039317954e-10
Temp 2: 3.1997365387318973e-10
Cycle: 6; Efficiency: 0.9999589492105335
Pri 1: 9.99370065823541e-07
Pri 2: 9.993700917382614e-07
Temp 1: 6.399082617384076e-10
Temp 2: 6.399341764593294e-10
Cycle: 7; Efficiency: 0.9999589229142298
Pri 1: 9.987301579176373e-07
Pri 2: 9.987302097792151e-07
Temp 1: 1.2797902207846395e-09
Temp 2: 1.2798420823631377e-09
Cycle: 8; Efficiency: 0.9999588702215008
Pri 1: 9.974503684094203e-07
Pri 2: 9.974504722634983e-07
Temp 1: 2.559527736501506e-09
Temp 2: 2.5596315905802006e-09
Cycle: 9; Efficiency: 0.9999587644316008
Pri 1: 9.948908421016906e-07
Pri 2: 9.948910503398154e-07
Temp 1: 5.118949660184387e-09
Temp 2: 5.119157898309939e-09
Cycle: 10; Efficiency: 0.9999585512150795
Pri 1: 9.897718953137677e-07
Pri 2: 9.897723139348765e-07
Temp 1: 1.0237686065123224e-08
Temp 2: 1.023810468623287e-08
Cycle: 11; Efficiency: 0.9999581181067771
Pri 1: 9.7953421505308e-07
Pri 2: 9.795350610263854e-07
Temp 1: 2.0474938973614262e-08
Temp 2: 2.0475784946920725e-08
Cycle: 12; Efficiency: 0.9999572241744039
Pri 1: 9.590592879358986e-07
Pri 2: 9.590610159597535e-07
Temp 1: 4.094898404024612e-08
Temp 2: 4.095071206410206e-08
Cycle: 13; Efficiency: 0.9999553167605227
Pri 1: 9.181103286655014e-07
Pri 2: 9.181139387457051e-07
Temp 1: 8.18960612542945e-08
Temp 2: 8.189967133449928e-08
Cycle: 14; Efficiency: 0.9999509417304484
Pri 1: 8.362143218009405e-07
Pri 2: 8.362222487313798e-07
Temp 1: 1.6378775126861994e-07
Temp 2: 1.6379567819906017e-07
Cycle: 15; Efficiency: 0.9999389959080549
Pri 1: 6.724267058021067e-07
Pri 2: 6.724464196692128e-07
Temp 1: 3.2756358033078687e-07
Temp 2: 3.275832941978939e-07
Cycle: 16; Efficiency: 0.999881092518708
Pri 1: 3.448636529415585e-07
Pri 2: 3.449405021781882e-07
Temp 1: 6.550694978218116e-07
Temp 2: 6.551463470584422e-07
Cycle: 17; Efficiency: 0.5264117174519147
Pri 1: 6.173497903170838e-13
Pri 2: 9.056777506975753e-11
Temp 1: 9.9991943222493e-07
Temp 2: 1.0000093826502103e-06
Cycle: 18; Efficiency: 4.55884719669062e-05
Pri 1: 3.4283980122736808e-19
Pri 2: 7.38063736992815e-15
Temp 1: 1.0000099926193623e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000099999996578e-06
Cycle: 19; Efficiency: 3.6901525033426808e-09
Pri 1: -7.56944722967757e-24
Pri 2: 6.014075684520175e-19
Temp 1: 1.0000099999993982e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 20; Efficiency: 3.006739577729103e-13
Pri 1: -4.26443257940018e-24
Pri 2: 5.0334412390713845e-23
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 21; Efficiency: 2.4499055249910828e-17
Pri 1: -4.261015212659181e-24
Pri 2: 1.3323945430461554e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 22; Efficiency: 3.537919550216741e-21
Pri 1: -4.264358355576793e-24
Pri 2: 1.328661776104943e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 23; Efficiency: 6.586578432833721e-24
Pri 1: -4.264651042496745e-24
Pri 2: 1.3289412897362976e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 24; Efficiency: -4.669280931707777e-22
Pri 1: -4.264322421569872e-24
Pri 2: 1.3295465343343283e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 25; Efficiency: -4.033381628412326e-18
Pri 1: -9.643336312842848e-25
Pri 2: 6.096401668505964e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 26; Efficiency: -1.7928462660600777e-22
Pri 1: -9.645834663351964e-25
Pri 2: 6.0970100763957804e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 27; Efficiency: 9.465002751917195e-18
Pri 1: 3.1143527079562413e-24
Pri 2: -1.6912120901785106e-23
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 28; Efficiency: -5.4327442351155336e-18
Pri 1: -4.2573287015899444e-24
Pri 2: 1.325157632876866e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 29; Efficiency: 2.220455013323325e-21
Pri 1: -4.264413609414534e-24
Pri 2: 1.3278015862657087e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 30; Efficiency: -9.181589730610556e-22
Pri 1: -4.264322788059294e-24
Pri 2: 1.3295471012197703e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 31; Efficiency: 5.4326757292416825e-18
Pri 1: 3.1152266062187542e-24
Pri 2: -1.691546240505624e-23
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 32; Efficiency: -9.463688877357565e-18
Pri 1: -9.63949706848734e-25
Pri 2: 6.091280936503942e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 33; Efficiency: 9.461116532403566e-18
Pri 1: 3.116935792777572e-24
Pri 2: -1.6912026850260163e-23
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 34; Efficiency: -5.428891311058792e-18
Pri 1: -4.2643615966129534e-24
Pri 2: 1.3271617390741832e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06
Cycle: 35; Efficiency: 5.429911312197918e-18
Pri 1: -4.2643615966129534e-24
Pri 2: 1.3271617390741832e-24
Temp 1: 1.0000099999999996e-06
Temp 2: 1.0000100000000007e-06


What does "incorrect" mean? What do you expect? What do you get instead? Please [edit] and clarify.

Incorrect means that the values are coming negative, I expect positive values for all variables.

Why do you say this is a precision issue?

Show some values, start, and shortly before and after the overflow.  It's hard to imagine the numbers just from reading the code.

You can use Decimal(). But, your initial inputs might be causing the problem.

Decimal() is not supported by fsolve function

After cycle 20, efficiency reached machine precision, further value can be considered as 0 up to float arithmetic precision.

Simply use x**2 instead of x:
...

def opt_func(x):
    """ Function for optimization. """
    # Converts all negative `x` to positive
    # `longdouble` might increase math operations precision
    return func(np.power(x, 2, dtype=np.longdouble))


for i in range(cycles):

    x_init = np.random.random(size = 7) * 0.001
    sol = fsolve(opt_func, x_init)

    sol = np.power(sol, 2, dtype=np.longdouble)
    print(i+1)

    # check that all values are positive
    print(sol)

    # check that solution close to zero
    print(func(sol))
    ...


even if you use np.longdouble, it is just going to be converted back to standard double precision in hybrd

@hybrd thx, important thing to know, this also explains why the answer doesn't change a lot when you use longdouble. Also to note this doesn't affect the main idea on how to convert function parameters to positive domain.
